# For jQgrid Subgrid,Service is not getting called through url attribute

Tags: javascript

This is my code how i am trying to include a sub grid in my jQgrid.

```js
 var receivedData = <% =GroupbyAgentJsonData %>
        jQuery("#" + '<%=reportJqGrid.ClientID%>').jqGrid({
            data: receivedData,
            datatype: "local",
            height: 270,
            width: "1130",
            colNames: ['Client Name', 'Return BatchID', 'Report Sent Date', 'Report Type', 'Attested Count', 'Status'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 20, stype: 'text', sortable: true },
                { name: 'Report_Sent_Id', index: 'Report_Sent_Id', width: 20, sortable: true },
                { name: 'Report_Sent_Date', index: 'Report_Sent_Date', width: 20, sortable: true },
                { name: 'Report_Type', index: 'Report_Type', width: 20, sortable: true },
                { name: 'Attestation_Count', index: 'Attestation_Count', width: 20, sortable: true },
                { name: 'Standard_Value', index: 'Standard_Value', width: 20, sortable: true }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            multiselect: false,
            subGrid: true,
            emptyrecords: "Record is not available",
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30],
            caption: "Billing Report",
            
            subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {

                // we pass two parameters
                // subgrid_id is a id of the div tag created whitin a table data
                // the id of this elemenet is a combination of the "sg_" + id of the row
                // the row_id is the id of the row
                // If we wan to pass additinal parameters to the url we can use
                // a method getRowData(row_id) - which returns associative array in type name-value
                // here we can easy construct the flowing

                var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
                subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
                pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
                $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "' class='scroll'></div>");
                var returnBatchId = $("#" + '<%=reportJqGrid.ClientID%>').jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'Report_Sent_Id');
                alert("Before Subgrid");
                jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                    url: 'frmBillingReport.aspx/GetSubGrid',
                    datatype: "json",
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    colNames: ['Client Id', 'Unique Id', 'Status','Origin','Date'],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: "Client_Id", index: "num", width: 70, key: true },
                        { name: "Unique_Id", index: "item", width: 80 },
                        { name: "Attestation_Status", index: "qty", width: 70, align: "right" },
                        { name: "Origin_Of_Attestation", index: "unit", width: 70, align: "right" },
                        { name: "Date_Of_Attestation", index: "total", width: 70, align: "right", sortable: false }
                        
                    ],
                    rowNum: 20,
                    pager: pager_id,
                    sortname: 'num',
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    height: '100%',
          
                });
             }
```

Subgrid Url is not calling the respective service.I am able to call the ColName and ColModel attribute.
Is this the right way to call the service?